# Connection to Twitch IRC fails without good reason in Python

Tags: python, sockets, chat, irc, twitch

I am currently trying to read messages cat channels Twitch. For this, I have read some guides and I learned it had to go through the IRC Twitch. I then found a few lines of simple code.

```
import socket
import string

HOST="irc.twitch.tv"
PORT=6667
NICK="TwitchUsername"
IDENT="TwitchUsername"
REALNAME="TwitchUsername"
CHANNEL="#ChannelNameHere"
PASSWORD="OAuth Password here" #From http://twitchapps.com/tmi/
readbuffer=""

s=socket.socket( )
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("PASS %s\r\n" % PASSWORD)
s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
s.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))
s.send("JOIN %s\r\n" % CHANNEL)

while 1:
    readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024)
    temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
    readbuffer=temp.pop( )

    for line in temp:
        line=string.rstrip(line)
        line=string.split(line)
        if len(line) > 3:
            print line
        if(line[0]=="PING"):
            s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
```

However, authentication does not proceed as planned, since I get the following message:

```
[':tmi.twitch.tv', 'NOTICE', '*', ':Login', 'unsuccessful']
```

I am using a valid OAuth Chat Password, and I see no reason that justifies this failure. Do you also have an error when you try with your username? Or do you have an idea of ​​the problem please?

Comment: Perhaps too many people are trying to play Pokemon?

Comment: @RobWatts Surely, but I did not try on #twitchplayspokemon, I tried on others channels and it failed for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your OAuth password needs to be sent as:

```
PASS oauth:twitch_oauth_token
```

which means that if you are putting in your token in the PASSWORD variable without the oauth: prefix, you should amend the pass line to:

```
s.send("PASS oauth:%s\r\n" % PASSWORD)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same `:tmi.twitch.tv NOTICE * :Error logging in`.

As noted in the readme ["Your nickname must be your Twitch username in lowercase"](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/IRC.md#connecting).

My issue was not making the `NICK` exactly my twitch username in lowercase (Not a very informative notice. So hopefully this saves someone else some time...).